# jquery autocomplete does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Using the example from the jquery website I have the following webpage.  I do not get any javascript errors when I type into the input box, nor does the autocomplete functionality work.  I'm using firefox on a mac.  What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
<div class="demo">
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use the [jQueryUI version](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)? It replaced the plugin one a long time ago.

Comment: load jquery ui and it will work

Comment: Yes, loading jquery ui worked.  Thanks jQuerybeast!

Comment: If you've found an acceptable answer, please write one and accept it. :-)